# Inserting initial data in database play framework jpa

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, playframework, sql-insert

I am using play 2.3 with jpa mysql. I have a admin in my database which should be created initially when creating database.I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) thread regarding it .So my `persistence.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                      value="META-INF/sql/data.sql"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

then I created a sql file in `META-INF/sql/data.sql`

```
INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `name`) VALUES(1, 'supersuperadmin')
```

but when I run my app it creates the database but it dint insert anything in`roles` table.

I have also tried creating `evolutions/default/1.sql` or also `2.sql` file with same data as above but it showed nothing.

so what I am doing wrong. How can I insert initial data in my database?

Comment: You could use evolutions script to insert your data.

Comment: You could also use the onStart method in Global and check every time your application starts whether your admin is already created in your DB.

Comment: @MonCalamari I have tried that check my edits it dint work

Comment: @Kris can you give an example of how you would run those insert sql from `Global.onStart()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onStart method in Global and check every time your application starts whether your admin is already created in your DB.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        checkAdmin();
    }

    private void checkAdmin() {
        // You have to start the transaction by hand - can't use @transactional
        JPA.withTransaction(() -> {
            // Check if admin exists in DB
            UserModel admin = JPA.em().find(UserModel.class, "admin");
            if (admin == null) {
                admin = // Create your admin here
                JPA.em().persist(admin);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to run an insert sql but how can user be found if its not created

Comment: JPA manages the insert SQL for you. Use JPA's persist. As far as I understood, you want to create an admin user if it doesn't exist yet when you start your application, don't you?

Comment: yes I want to but I have 4 or 5 tables related with that table like admin,roles,permission etc so I was looking for some JPA way or play way like we create 1.sql and 2.sql

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.

Comment: ok, thanks a ton for you efforts means alot I will try this if I dint get  any solution with jpa